# Pattern matching Strings

Tags: python

I have an array of strings:

Input:

```
["series-a-funding", "series-b-financials","series-c-funding","series-b-funding","abc-funding","raised-acd", "fund-series-a", "fund-series-b"]
```

and I want to filter all the strings which has series-a, series-b, series-c in the strings. My sample output will be

```
["series-a-funding", "series-b-financials","series-c-funding","series-b-funding","fund-series-a", "fund-series-b"]
```

I have tried something like this

```
def interesting(textInput):
    textInput = textInput.lower()
    if any([word in textInput for word in ['fund-series-%s' or 'series-%s-funding' or 'series-%s-financing' %i for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]]):
        return True
    return False
```

But no luck. Can anyone help me with this. I am new to python so don't have much idea on this.

Comment: I suggest you using regex against your strings to check if they match your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    '^(fund-series-[abcd]|series-[abcd]-funding|series-[abcd]-financing)$', 
    re.IGNORECASE
)

def interesting(word):
    return bool(pattern.match(word))
```

We declare pattern, described by your rules and your presented code and then declare function to check if word matched the pattern (case-insensitive)

Or if you need more global *series-a/b/c/d* pattern, then `search` will do:

```
pattern = re.compile('series-[abcd]', re.IGNORECASE)

def interesting(word):
    return bool(pattern.search(word))
```

Comment: How to search a particular word in regex compile. For example I am looking for "appoints" word and I am trying something like this \b(?:appoints)\b but no luck

Answer (score 1):

This solution will filter strings matching the regex `series-[abc]`:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('series-[abc]')
output_list = list(filter(regex.search, input_list))
```

The expression `filter(regex.search, input_list)` applies the function `regex.search` to each element in the list and returns only those elements for which the result is `True` when converted to `bool`. We make use of the fact that the `regex.search` function returns a `SRE_Match` object in the case of match, which evaluates to `True` when converted to `bool`, or a `None` in the case of mismatch, which evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = ["series-a-funding", "series-b-financials","series-c-funding","series-b-funding","abc-funding","raised-acd", "fund-series-a", "fund-series-b"] 


[i for i in s if bool(re.match(r"series-['a','b','c']+", i))]
```

gives

```
['series-a-funding', 'series-b-financials', 'series-c-funding', 'series-b-funding']
```

Comment: This will not find strings `"fund-series-a"` and `"fund-series-b"` because `re.match` only tries to find the match at the beginning of a string. `re.search` does the matching also in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a list which contains the string with necessary keywords. Not whether they are true or false. Then instead of using `return True` or `return False` you should try return a list.

Another problem in your code is using methods incorrectly. `lower ()` method is applicable for strings only, not for lists. Therefore you should have used `textInput = text.lower() for text in textInput`

Also you would want to return the true string. Not its lower cased clone. Therefore converting original list to lowercase at the beginning of the function is inadvisable. Instead you could lower case each string when comparing and not at the beginning.

Here is a simple program I have written:

```
textList = ["series-a-funding", "series-b-financials","series-c-funding","series-b-funding","abc-funding","raised-acd", "fund-series-a", "fund-series-b"]

def printStrings (strings):
    return [string for string in textList if 'series-a' in string.lower () or 'series-b' in string.lower () or 'series-c' in string.lower ()]

print printStrings (strings)
```